# Github push didn't use user in the config file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, command, push

[screenshot config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGzBW.png)

[screenshot push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhNXY.png)

I changed my git account but it seems like it still pushed to the old account even though I've changed the config both global config and local config. I have searched multiple resources, and none of seems to work. Why does this happen?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[As the Git FAQ outlines](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name), `user.name` has no effect on authentication, and is instead customarily your personal name:

> You should put your personal name, generally a form using a given name and family name. For example, the current maintainer of Git uses "Junio C Hamano". This will be the name portion that is stored in every commit you make.
>
> This configuration doesn’t have any effect on authenticating to remote services; for that, see `credential.username` in git-config(1).

If you're using HTTPS, it's likely that credentials are saved in your credential manager and they're being used without prompting.  As [the Git FAQ specifies](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials), you can reset them like so:

```
$ echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```